# Amazon Alexa: Certain utterances not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have two utterances:

SampleQuestion what's the {Currency} {Currencytwo} rate

SampleQuestion what is the {Currency} {Currencytwo} rate

The first one works (what's), while the second one doesn't (what is)

What could be a possible reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voice recognition is something that is very hard to test. What is and is not recognized can vary depending on the person speaking, background noise, etc. There are a few things to try to debug your problem.

1. In the companion app Alexa often types "what it thought it heard". You might check this to see what Alexa thinks it heard when it didn't recognize something.
2. You can type specific phrases into the simulator on the development page for your skill. This can test specific renderings. However, because it bypasses the voice recognition layer it is only good for debugging the specifics of your interaction model.
3. Alexa performs poorly when you have two lots that are not separated by static text. You might consider if you can re-phrase your utterance to have a separating words between the two, or to ask for it as two separate utterances.
4. If either of your slots are custom slots, you might consider what their content is. Alexa doesn't recognize things one word at a time. It looks at the entire sequence of sounds holistically. It matches each possibility against what it heard, and picks the one with the highest confidence value. Since currencies are often foreign words, that might be perturbing things. Try cutting down your list and see if that improves things.